# Apache Web Server Load Testing ( Running on Centos6)

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, performance

How can i easily test how many requests my web server ( Apache) setup can handle without dropping a connection or timing out.

Is there any simple bash script or i have to use some sophisticated stress testing tool.

Comment: Im not sure of any way of doing it via bash script but Apache does have stress test tool you can use to run against your server. The tool is called Apache JMeter.

Answer (score 5):

You can test this using `ab`, a software that resides inside `apache2-utils` package. Example:

```
ab -r -n 100 -c 10 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://mysite.mydomain.com/
```

- `-r`: Avoid exiting on socket errors.
- `-n`: Number of requests to perform.
- `-c`: Number of multiple requests running in concurrency.
- `-k`: Enable HTTP KeepAlive. Means it will perform multiple requests per Http session.
- `-H`: Custom header. It depens a lot on how your site is configured.

Here is the result of a test i made in a simple site with just an index page(php):

```
# ab -r -n 200 -c 20 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://intranet.example.com/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking intranet.example.com (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.2.15
Server Hostname:        intranet.example.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        10276 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   38.344 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      2132800 bytes
HTML transferred:       2055200 bytes
Requests per second:    5.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       3834.421 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       191.721 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          54.32 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:  2869 3813 383.1   3649    5205
Waiting:     2868 3781 380.4   3613    5161
Total:       2869 3814 383.1   3650    5205

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   3650
  66%   3763
  75%   3971
  80%   4318
  90%   4451
  95%   4530
  98%   4634
  99%   5093
 100%   5205 (longest request)
```

However, you will have to take some time between tests, ensure that your httpd service is not under heavy load, and increase all the parameters to hit harder on your server. As far as i know, there is no tool that would evaluate this output and increase performance measuring parameters on-the-fly.

**Links**:

- [ab manpage](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) - Apache HTTP sever benchmarking tool

Comment: I also recommend this tool, nice!